# The area of the intersection of two ovals (ellipses)?

Tags: python, geometry, polygon, shapely

I need to calculate the amount of two oval intersects in a python program.
I know in [shaply](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) there is a function that return true if two object has intersects. As like as this:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
p1=Polygon([(0,0),(1,1),(1,0)])
p2=Polygon([(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)])
print p1.intersects(p2)
```

is there any library or function That help me?
Thanks.

Comment: doesn't your code work?

Comment: So you want the area of the intersection?

Comment: @picmate It's work correctly. But I want the amount of intersection. This function return boolean value.

Comment: @FamousJameous Yes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? (the polygon that results from the intersection)

```
x = p1.intersection(p2)
x.area
```

Find more information in the documentation [here](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html)

Comment: Thanks. It's so close to what I want. I want to calculate the amount of this area.